# PageViewController shows part of other viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with 2 `UIViewControllers` which both have a `UIImageView` as background with content mode set to `scaleAspectFill`. This causes for some reason that the second `UIViewController` is partly visible when scrolling first to the second `UIViewController` and than scrolling back to the first `UIViewController`.

The reproduction project can be found here: https://github.com/Jasperav/PageViewControllerGlitch. The code is also beneath the photo.

Photo (the space is the first `UIViewController`, the green part is the second `UIViewController`):
[image]

Code (I don't use storyboards, for a reproduction path with the correct window, use the github link):

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    private let pageViewControllers: [UIViewController] = [VC1(), VC2()]

    init() {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)

        dataSource = self
        delegate = self

        setViewControllers([pageViewControllers.first!], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return pageViewControllers.count
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let index = pageViewControllers.index(of: viewController), index > 0 else { return nil }

        let previousIndex = index - 1

        return pageViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let index = pageViewControllers.index(of: viewController), (index + 1) != pageViewControllers.count else { return nil }

        return pageViewControllers[index + 1]
    }
}

class VC: UIViewController {
    init(background: UIImage) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: background)

        backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)

        backgroundImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        backgroundImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class VC1: VC {
    init() {
        super.init(background: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bg1"))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class VC2: VC {
    init() {
        super.init(background: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bg2"))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use AspectFill as the content mode, if the image is larger than the UImageView's dimension, the image overflows. To solve this issue you can clip its subviews:

```
backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
backgroundImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Another solution is to try another content mode like `.scaleToFill`. 
Hope this helps, i just tried this solutions in your demo project and both worked.

Comment: I should have known this :P Thank you! :)